# How to add more actions to a column in Magento grid?

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, grid, column, action

In Magento 1.9 I add a column to Sales Grid using an observer. I want to show more actions instead only one action.

With my code, in my column I see a select box, with the two actions. Instead I want to see the two actions, one under the other.

This is my observer:

```
class VendorName_ModuleName_Model_ObserverAddColumn
{
    public function addColumnToGrid(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();

        if (!($block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid) || $block->getNameInLayout() != 'sales_order.grid')
            return $this;

        // Add a new column rigth after the "view" column
        $block->addColumnAfter('view', [
        'header' => $block->__('Header'),
        'width' => '60px',
        'index' => 'index_example',
        'type'   => 'action',
        'sortable' => false,
        'getter'   => 'getId',
        'actions'   => array(
                array(
                        'caption'   => Mage::helper('ModuleName')->__('One'),
                        'url'       => array('base'=> 'routerName/controllerName/actionName'),
                        'field'     => 'id'
                ),
                array(
                        'caption'   => Mage::helper('ModuleName')->__('Two'),
                        'url'       => array('base'=> 'routerName/controllerName/actionName2'),
                        'field'     => 'id'
                    )
        ),
        'filter' => false
        ], 'entity_id');

       return $this;
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This plugin will solve all grid related problems. Please test it on development 1st. https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/enhanced-admin-grids-editor.html

Comment: Thanks but I'm searching a solution without installing another plugin..